# Run as Android Application

Tags: android, eclipse

I start Eclipse as a fresh install with all tools updated

I created a virtual device Platform 4 Api lvl 14 Cpu Arm

I try to run the default Hello world  by "Run as Android Application" and nothing happens, literally nothing. If the VD is not open when I click Run as Android App then the Virtual device doesn't load up.  If it is already opened then the application doesn't load into the device. Basically clicking the "Run as Android Application produces no error log and no results. I have tried this with a number of differently configured V Devices and everything seems to run fine besides not being able to load a program onto a Virtual device.

Its probably something obvious but its preventing me getting started, any help please?

Comment: have you defined your activity in AndroidManifest?

Comment: As stated in my question the VD Api was set at 14,   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

Comment: Activate console tab for android

Comment: have defined the launcher activity in manifest

Comment: What do you see in your logCat?

Comment: Activate console tab?  1.Click Window > Preferences.
2.Expand C/C++ and Build, then click Console. Is this correct. If so then still no console tab appears

Comment: logCat means nothing to me or the Android ADT help

Comment: Inside my manifest
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

go to Project properties(Right click on the project select properties from context menu)

Select Run/Debug Settings from left pane

Delete All entries then Add a new one

In project filed select your project

Comment: I might be a bit late but , Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah just a few years :D RIP Eclipse :)